# How do I calculate the boundaries of a scaled map?

Tags: google-maps, maps, gis

Given a bounding box on a map (NE lat & lng + SW lat & lng) as well as the origin, how would I determine the bounding box points if the map were scaled by a factor of X?

For instance, if I wanted to double the scale of the bounding box (X = 2) how would I calculate the new NE lat & lng and SW lat & lng?